Question on maths behind Floyd Cycle Finding Algorithm
So in our class our professor asked us a quesiton on the logic behind Floyd's Cycle Algorithm. FCA is based upon two pointers, one slow and one fast pointer, both of these pointers traverse the linked list and if they meet we know a loop exist, if they don't a loop doesn't exist. The slow pointer is only allowed to jump one node at a time while the fast pointer is made to jump two nodes at a time. Now, from what I could gather the logic behind is this algorithm has something to do with modular arithmetic.
Let us consider n number of nodes that form a loop and label them from 0 to n-1. Let me take an example of five nodes for the sake of explaining it to you, Lets say that both the nodes are starting from node 0. If we are to represent their travel in the form of modular addition then it can be represented as +1mod(5) and +2mod(5). If we check their travel we see that they are bound to meet at some point,
0+1mod(5) = 1_______0+2mod(5) = 2
1+1mod(5) = 2_______2+2mod(5) = 4
2+1mod(5) = 3_______4+2mod(5) = 1
3+1mod(5) = 4_______1+2mod(5) = 3
4+1mod(5) = 0_______3+2mod(5) = 0 (They meet)
Can anyone here tell me the reason as to why we get the same output no matter where we start with at some turn with +1modn and +2modn. Is there any mathematical proof that this is bound to happen or a property of modulus operator. Will appreciate any help provided. Thank you.
